# Structures for dummies

Tags: c++, methods, struct, constructor, operator-overloading

I'm studying structures in C++... I understood the basic concept of it and as far as I know the are meant to list a series of items in a more compact way.... however I came across an example where I don't understand what's going on:

```
struct cuComplex {
    float   r; // real part of a complex number
    float   i; // imaginary part of a complex number
    /* !!! I DON'T UNDERSTAND FROM HERE !!! */
    cuComplex( float a, float b ) : r(a), i(b)  {}
    float magnitude2( void ) { return r * r + i * i; }
    cuComplex operator*(const cuComplex& a) {
        return cuComplex(r*a.r - i*a.i, i*a.r + r*a.i);
    }
    cuComplex operator+(const cuComplex& a) {
        return cuComplex(r+a.r, i+a.i);
    }
    /* !!! TO HERE. !!! */
};
```

It seems to me that some sort of function is defined inside but I don't understand how that is possible and how I should interpret it.

## Q. Is there some reference where I can read about this in order to have a better idea of what is going on?

Comment: You can define functions for a `struct` just as a `class` can have functions. They are defining 1) the constructor 2) a `magnitude2` function 3) the `*` multiplication operator 4) the `+` addition opoerator

Comment: You should at least know what language you are learning, and also be warned that C != C++. Many times, a "natural" answer for one will be very different from the other (and quite possibly might not even compile).

Comment: Let's please not edit away the fact that this was asked as a C question?  The entire problem is that he is trying to compile C++ code in a C compiler.

Comment: "is there also some reference where i can read about it in order to have a better idea of what is going on?" Yes, any basic C++ book.

Comment: The code is actually part of a cuda "C" study case... since i'm not a programmer and i just got started i believe it's reasonable having trouble distinguishing from c to c++

Comment: @FedericoGentile Sorry for all the haters, there are a lot of helpful people here if you can stick it out. +1 to encourage you. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266370/consideration-for-removing-the-downvote-button-from-questions/266670#266670

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is like a `class`, [<sub>with the exception of default member protection</sub>](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/#struct_and_union), and it has member variables `r` and `i`, read here for more: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/

```
struct cuComplex {
    float   r;
    float   i; // imaginary part of a complex number
```

This is a constructor, read here for more: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/#constructors

```
    cuComplex( float a, float b ) : r(a), i(b)  {}
```

This is a method or member function, if you've made it through the first like you've read about that, but if you want a more concise example read here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_classes#Member_functions

```
    float magnitude2( void ) { return r * r + i * i; }
```

These are overloaded `operator`s read here for more: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/#overloading_operators

```
    cuComplex operator*(const cuComplex& a) {
        return cuComplex(r*a.r - i*a.i, i*a.r + r*a.i);
    }
    cuComplex operator+(const cuComplex& a) {
        return cuComplex(r+a.r, i+a.i);
    }
};
```

If you have a specific question beyond this, you can comment on this post and I'll try to help explain.

Answer (score 2):

struct in C++ is basically the same as classes with one difference. In class defualt access specifier is private whereas in struct it's public.

So what you're seeing in that code are:-

constructors, overloaded operators +,* for you struct and a method to compute magnitude of a complex number.